# Textbox focus skipping on pressing TAB

Tags: c#, winforms

I have app where I have `multiple textboxes` and I would like to do when the user is focused in one textbox when he presses `TAB button on keyboard` I would like to skip the focus into other textbox which I will set.

Is there any way to do that easily? I have 20 textboxes in this form and I need it to skip from textbox1 to textbox2 to textbox3....textbox20 when press the TAB key.

Comment: You can reorganize `TabIndex` or set `TabStop = false` on the controls you want to skip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the `TabIndex` property, which is an integer value you can assign to controls either in code or in the designer properties window:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex.aspx

See also the `TabStop` property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop.aspx

Example:

```
TextBox1.TabIndex = 2;
TextBox2.TabStop = false;
TextBox3.TabIndex = 99;
```

With focus on `TextBox1`, pressing tab will jump to `TextBox3`, then back to `TextBox1`, and obviously `TextBox2` is skipped.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to  set the **tab index** of each text box,

you can set either from the properties window (for each textbox ) or set by selecting the menu

`view->Taborder`.

you can set the tab index and by pressing the Tab key the control wil automatically transfer from 1 textbox to another.

Answer (score 0):

in c# every `Control` has a property called `tabStop` and `tabIndex`

setting the `tabIndex` one after the other will make that when you press tab from one one `textBox` you'll get focus on the other

if you want a control not to get focus when pressing tab, though i'm not sure u want, but your question isn't clear on that so i didn't want you to miss it, put `true` in `tabStop`